# Number of paths from root to a node in a tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

How to prove inductively the total number of paths from the root to all leaves in a given tree?

From what I understand, one should show how to find the number of paths to a specific leaf, then use induction to find the total number of paths to all leaves. However, I am not quite sure how to show the this step mathematically.

Comment: Could you please be more clear in explaining exactly what it is that you want to prove?

Comment: One of the characteristics of a tree is that there is a unique path between any given pair of nodes.

Comment: So how to find the number of paths from root to a specific node?

Comment: The title asks for the number of paths from root to a node, which is 1. The questions asks for the number of paths to all leaves, which is impossible to answer without knowing the tree.

Answer (score 7):

1. Each leaf in a tree can be reached by exactly one path from the root node.
2. If there are $N$ leaves, there are $N$ paths from the root to a leaf node.
3. If there were more, there would be a leaf node with two paths to it. This contradicts Statement 1.
4. If there were fewer, there would be a leaf node with no paths to it, meaning it is not a leaf of the tree. This is a contradiction as well.

Therefore, the number of paths you're looking for is the number of leaves.

Comment: that's very helpful. thx

Comment: "If there are N leaves, there are N paths from the root to a leaf node." ==> should be: "If there are N leaves, there are N paths from the root to ALL leaf nodes".

(I indeed want to believe that the author of the original answer meant to say: "N paths from the root to ALL leaf nodes" but what he actually wrote is "N paths from the root to a leaf node" -- so, this is just a correction on English writing, not about the underlying logic of reasoning!)

Comment: @charlesqwu I've reread what I've written and I think it would be more proper to write it as "there are $N$ paths from the root to a leaf node, one per leaf node." Your correction doesn't really disambiguate and it doesn't lend itself to the spirit of the statement. The original statement was to describe the quantity of "paths from the root to a leaf node." This statement doesn't make any claims about the coverage of all these paths, but it's not important. It's an exact statement about how many paths from the root there are at all. The rest of the answer is pigeonhole, which handles coverage.